# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found when using rest_v2 in Jasper server URL

Tags: java, rest, jasperserver

I am working on Rest web services to connect my application to jasper report server. when i use 
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest/login?j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin, its working fine

but http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/login?j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin is not working and it giving HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

why am i not able to use rest_v2 in my url. since REST (now called v1) API is being deprecated, i am not allowed to use it.

can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one for the rest_v2

http://host:port/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/login?j_username=userID%7Corganization_id&j_password=password